# Configure Automapper 9.0 in .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, automapper-9

I followed the official documentation, stating the shift from static API as regards Automapper 9.0 but still I am unable to make it work inside my c# dotnet core App. I get the following exception:

> "AutoMapperMappingException: missing type map configuration or
>   unsupported mapping" in my controller class."

Can you show me please the configuration steps as regards Automapper 9.0?

Here the steps I performed:

**Startup.cs**

```
      var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
        {
           mc.AddProfile(new MyMapperProfile());
         });

   IMapper mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();
   services.AddSingleton(mapper);
```

**MyMapperProfile class**

```
CreateMap<MasterData.Models.SupplierMaterial, SupplierMaterial>().
            ForMember(dto => dto.TechnicalDrawings, conf => conf.MapFrom(ol =>
                       ol.TechnicalDrawings.Select(v => v.Id)));

            CreateMap<MasterData.Models.WarehouseUbication, WarehouseUbication>().
            ForMember(dto => dto.MaterialCode, conf => conf.MapFrom(ol => ol.Material.Code));

            CreateMap<MasterData.Models.TechnicalDrawing, TechnicalDrawing>().
                ForMember(dto => dto.MaterialCode, conf => conf.MapFrom(ol => ol.Materials.Select(v => v.Code)))
               .ForMember(dto => dto.SupplierMaterialCode, conf => conf.MapFrom(ol => ol.SupplierMaterials.Select(v => v.Code)));

            CreateMap<MasterData.Models.MaterialDocument, MaterialDocument>().
                ForMember(dto => dto.Materials, conf => conf.MapFrom(ol => ol.Materials.Select(v => v.Code)));

            CreateMap<MasterData.Models.Material, Material>().
                ForMember(dto => dto.WarehouseUbications, conf => conf.MapFrom(ol => ol.WarehouseUbications.Select(v => v.Code)))
                .ForMember(dto => dto.SupplierMaterials, conf => conf.MapFrom(ol => ol.SupplierMaterials.Select(v => v.Code)))
                .ForMember(dto => dto.TechnicalDrawingID, conf => conf.MapFrom(ol => ol.TechnicalDrawing.Id))
                .ForMember(dto => dto.MaterialDocuments, conf => conf.MapFrom(ol => ol.MaterialDocuments.Select(v => v.Materials)));


            //var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        }



    }
}
```

**Controller class**

```
public MaterialController(IMasterDataService masterService, IMapper mapper)
        {
            this.masterDataService = masterService;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }



  //[route]
     public List<Material> getAllMaterials()
      {
                List<Material> materialsList = new List<Material>();           

                foreach (MasterData.Models.Material m in masterDataService.GetMaterials())
                {
                    _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Contracts.Material>>(m);
                }            

                return materialsList;
            }
```

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core

Comment: I see no mapping from `MasterData.Models.Material` to `IEnumerable<Contracts.Material>`

Comment: Hi @trailmax, sorry I did not post the complete class. As you can see the last mapping is about contracts

Comment: you issue has nothing to do with the fact that you like to call you application Microservices. Please use the term with more thought!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in your controller code. You should either map directly from one collection type to another, using the built in collection mapping support, or map each element indiviually, building the target collection yourself. Currently, you're just discarding the mapped objects and returning an empty list.

```
public List<Material> getAllMaterials()
{
   var materialsList = _mapper.Map<List<Contracts.Material>>(masterDataService.GetMaterials())

   return materialsList;
}
```

or:

```
public List<Material> getAllMaterials()
{
  List<Material> materialsList = new List<Material>();           

  foreach (MasterData.Models.Material m in masterDataService.GetMaterials())
  {
     var mapped = _mapper.Map<Contracts.Material>(m);
     materialsList.Add(mapped);
  }            

  return materialsList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MasterDataMapperProfile : Profile
{
    public MyMapperProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<MasterData.Models.SupplierMaterial, SupplierMaterial>().
            ForMember(dto => dto.TechnicalDrawings, conf => conf.MapFrom(ol => 
                       ol.TechnicalDrawings.Select(v => v.Id)));
    }
}
```

I think this should fix it. At the moment inside the profile you're creating a new config, registering your mapping on that config and then that config is discared.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately even after this change I still get the same Exception. I guess there's something wrong in the Startup class...

Answer (score 0):

Your controller code should be like this

```
 public List<Material> getAllMaterials()
 {
            List<Material> materialsList = _mapper.Map<List<Contracts.Material>>(masterDataService.GetMaterials());

            return materialsList;
  }
```

Otherwise you are mapping a single object to a list. Also you are returning empty list.